# R.string not working onCreate()

Tags: android

I need to display a 'dynamic text' which is concatenated by 2 `R.strings` and 1 `String` variable:

The fact is I need to display it at the beginning so on the `onCreate()` method, but I get this error:

```
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #
```

This is what I tried to do:

```
text2.setText(R.string.still + playersAmount + R.string.LastRemaining); //Display Single
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I tell you to call first one phone number, then the other, you can't just sum them up and call the result. This is what you're doing.

`R.string.some_id` is an *integer* that *maps* to a string and can be localized. The localization works by mapping the same `id` to different values for different languages. It can only be resolved though, if you look it up using its `id`, and only that. Modifying that id will lead to invalid results: This is the error you see.

You need to get those 2 Strings seperately.

```
getString(R.string.first) + playersAmount + getString(R.string.second)
```

Then the normal rules for string concatenation apply.

Also, you should have a look on string formatters since they reduce the need for manual concatenation, which will lead to problems if you ever add multiple languages.

```
<string name="formatted_string">I have %d players</string>
```

Can also be used like this:

```
context.getString(R.string.formatted_string, playersAmount);
```

Comment: Just had to edit that 'id' to 'name' , but yet, it works like a charm and it's so clean now with the second format, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

call `getResources().getString(R.string.still)`

and `getResources().getString(R.string.LastRemaining)`

otherwise you are just referencing an integer value from R.java adding it to playersAmount and then adding another integer value from R.java and Android is looking for this sum of ints as the Strings resource id.

Comment: @FET please see the short description i added, hopefully this helps explain why this isn't working for you

Answer (score 0):

A more complete explanation of the solution to your problem (that builds on inner_class7's explanation) is that you'll need to do the following:

```
// Get Strings from resources
String still = getResources().getString(R.sting.still);
String lastRemaining = getResources.getString(R.string.LastRemaining);

// Concatenate Strings and set on TextView
text2.setText(still + playersAmount + lastRemaining);
```

As he mentioned, when you say R.string.still, you're really talking about an integer reference, which isn't what you want to do here. The magic that happens here is that getString is "knows" that you want the String associated with that particular ID. Let me know if you have any questions.

Answer (score 0):

When you do `R.string.still + playersAmount + R.string.LastRemaining` you are juste adding 3 `int` together (and looking for a resource string at the result)

If you wanna get a `String` from resources you must use `getString(int)`

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context.html#getString(int)

for you solution `text2.setText(getString(R.string.still) + playersAmount + getString(R.string.LastRemaining));`

I suggest you use a string with parameters `<string name="stillLastRemaining">Still %d last remaining</string>` and use `text2.setText(getString(R.string.stillLastRemaining, playersAmount));`